# How can I store a lot of arrays in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a function that through recursion prints every combination of numbers of an input array.

```
public class comb {
    public static void main(String[] args)

        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();


        int[] test = {1,2,3,4};
        combinations(test,2,0,new int[2]);

        listToString(list);
    }


    static void combinations(int[] arr, int n, int pos, int[] result){
        if(n == 0){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            return;
        }
        for(int i = pos; i <= arr.length - n; i++){
            result[result.length - n] = arr[i];
            combinations(arr,n-1,pos+1,result);
        }
    }
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
```

What should I do if instead of having each array printed, I want it added to a list? I can't just add result to the list because it is constantly changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways you might achieve it...

## You could...

Make `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();` a `static` global

```
public class comb {
    static List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Then you could just add the values to the `ArrayList`...

```
static void combinations(int[] arr, int n, int pos, int[] result) {
    if (n == 0) {
        list.add(result);
        return;
    }
```

But this is generally a bad idea, is sloppy programming and leads to bad habits

## You could...

Pass a reference of the `List` to the `combinations` method...

```
static void combinations(int[] arr, int n, int pos, int[] result, List<int[]> list) {
    if (n == 0) {
        list.add(Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length));
        return;
    }
```

This is better, as it makes the API re-usable and capable of been called multiple times within the same instance of the program without otherwise destroying what was in the `List`, like the previous example

## You could...

Have the `combinations` method return a `List`...

```
static List<int[]> combinations(int[] arr, int n, int pos, int[] result) {
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>(25);
    if (n == 0) {
        list.add(Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length));
    } else {
        for (int i = pos; i <= arr.length - n; i++) {
            result[result.length - n] = arr[i];
            list.addAll(combinations(arr, n - 1, pos + 1, result));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is kind of cool in the fact that you don't need to care about how the `List` was created, only that it will return all combinations of the `arr` to your specifications.  It's probably not as efficient as the previous example, as you are creating a new `List` on each recursion, but does hide the implementation details

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the array, and add the copy to the list.

```
static void combinations(int[] arr, int n, int pos, int[] result, List<int[]> allResults){
    if(n == 0){
        allResults.add(Arrays.copyOf(result));
        return;
    }
    // etc...
```

Comment: It could be me, but I believe [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) requires a `newLength` parameter. I'll forgive you, cause I missed it too ;)